# MySQLカラム置換挿入

Tags: mysql

カラムA
あいちけん
いわてけん
えひめけん
が入っています。最初の1文字をカラムBに追加するにはどうすればよいでしょうか

理想
カラムB
あ
い
え

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT()` という関数があります。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/string-functions.html#function_left

次のクエリで出来ると思います。

```
UPDATE テーブル名 SET カラムB=LEFT(カラムA, 1);
```